# Run MAUI app with Mac Catalyst under MacOS in system tray (Background)

Tags: macos, background, maui, system-tray, mac-catalyst

I'm trying to write a MAUI app that runs in the SystemTray. I managed to do this on Windows. Unfortunately I can't figure out how to get this to work under MacOS.

I created the system tray based on this model:
[WeatherTwentyOne](https://github.com/davidortinau/WeatherTwentyOne/tree/4044b7c35459848af973db7e9e96f521b005d9ba)

My solution, so that the application under Windows continues to run in the system tray after it is closed:

```
        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MainPage = new AppShell();
        }

        protected override Window CreateWindow(IActivationState activationState)
        {
            Window window = base.CreateWindow(activationState);

#if WINDOWS
            window.Created += (s, e) =>
            {
                var handle = WinRT.Interop.WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(window.Handler.PlatformView);
                var id = Microsoft.UI.Win32Interop.GetWindowIdFromWindow(handle);
                appWindow = Microsoft.UI.Windowing.AppWindow.GetFromWindowId(id);
                appWindow.Closing += (s, e) =>
                {
                    e.Cancel = true;
                    appWindow.Hide();
                };
            };
        }
```

Unfortunately, I can't find any information that will help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the Mac Apps, you could create a new [NSStatusItem](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsstatusitem?language=objc) on the right-top to make it look like the system tray on Windows mashine. And [`NSStatusBar.SystemStatusBar`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsstatusbar/1530619-systemstatusbar)  needs to be configured in the [DidFinishLaunching](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622921-application?language=objc) method of AppDelegate.

The key is that `NSStatusBar` only supports MacOS 10.0+(please see [Apple's NSStatusBar Doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsstatusbar?language=objc)).

MAUI Apps for the Mac platform use MacCatalyst (please see [MAUI supported platforms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/supported-platforms)). Since this feature is not supported with MacCatalyst API by Apple, you couldn't achive this functionality through MAUI.

Comment: So you say that it's not possible under MAUI. As I understand it from my research, it's because Mac Catalyst doesn't have full access to AppKit. That's why I don't have access to NSWindow etc. from MAUI. I saw that someone created a workaround with Swift so that they got full access to AppKit. Wouldn't something like this also be possible for MAUI? Someone else recommended [H.NotifyIcon](https://github.com/HavenDV/H.NotifyIcon) to me, but I can't get it to work under MacOS. Does anyone have experience with this tool?

Comment: As explained in the 'README' document of the 'H.NotifyIcon' GitHub , they didn't support MacOS. Usually, the workaround to access AppKit is to use the MacOS SDK or frameworks in a MacCatalyst project. If you want to use the workaround created by others with Swift in MAUI, you could try to bind that library.

Please refer to the Xamarin doc-[Bind iOS Swift libraries - Xamarin | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/binding-swift/), and then adjust a version of MAUI.